# Update form from dialog

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable within a form; in the dataTable I have a button which pops up a dialog if clicked; after editing(or not) I want to close the dialog and refresh the datatable.

I want to to this through the ajax event "close", so even if the clicks on cancel button, or closes the dialog by clicking escape or the "x" in the bar -> he should land in my closeDialog()-method and refresh the dataTable.

The only issue is that i don't know how to refresh the dataTable.

Here is my dataTable(in the header is my button which pops up the dialog):

```
<p:dataTable id="nzTable" widgetVar="nzTableW" emptyMessage="Keine Todos gefunden"
        var="currentTableItem" value="#{nichtZugTableController.dataModel}" paginator="true" rows="15"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20, 25, 30, 1000" lazy="false" paginatorPosition="bottom"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        currentPageReportTemplate="( Treffer {totalRecords} ) ( Seite {currentPage} von {totalPages} )"
        filteredValue="#{nichtZugTableController.filteredTodos}" filterDelay="500" filterEvent="keyup"
        editable="true" sortBy="#{currentTableItem.angelegtAm}" sortOrder="descending"
        rendered="#{loginBean.loggedIn and mitViewController.leiterViewActiv and leiterTreeController.nzTableActive}"
        selection="#{nichtZugTableController.selectedNZTodos}" rowKey="#{currentTableItem.meldungId}"
        resizableColumns="false" style="min-width:1200px !important; "> 

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton value="Zuordnen" id="nzAllTableOrdeZuButton" ajax="true" partialSubmit="true"
                process="@this" label="ToDo einem Mitarbeiter zuordnen" oncomplete="zuordnenDialogW.show();"
                disabled="#{not nichtZugTableController.hasSelectedNZTodos}"
                action="#{nichtZugTableController.doToDoArrayToList()}" style="float: left;" />
            <pe:tooltip for="nzAllTableOrdeZuButton" value="Ausgwählte ToDos einem Benutzer zuweisen"
                myPosition="left center" atPosition="right center" showEffect="fadeIn" hideEffect="fadeOut"
                showDelay="700" />
            <h:outputText value="#{nichtZugTableController.tableHeaderName}"
                style="color:#cf0008; font-size: 22px;" />
        </f:facet> 

        ...

</p:dataTable>
```

Here is my dialog:

```
<body>
<ui:composition>
    <h:form id="zuordnenDialogForm">
        <p:dialog id="zuordnenDialog" widgetVar="zuordnenDialogW" closeOnEscape="true" dynamic="true"
            header="Zuordnung" appendToBody="false" draggable="true" modal="true" resizable="false">
            <p:ajax event="close"  listener="#{zuordnenDialogController.closeDialog()}" />

             ...

        </p:dialog>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here is a picture, maybe it helps

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGjes.jpg

Comment: I tried already `update=":nzTableForm:nzTable"` but I get following error: `Cannot find component with identifier ":nzTableForm:nzTable" referenced from "zuordnenDialogForm:zuordnenDialog"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
<p:ajax event="close"  listener="#{zuordnenDialogController.closeDialog()}" update=":nzTable"/>
```

update=":nzTable" with full path, may be: :form_main:nzTable

i want to comment, but i don't have enought reputation.

Comment: Yes, I tried , but i get following error : `Cannot find component with identifier ":nzTableForm:nzTable" referenced from "zuordnenDialogForm:zuordnenDialog"`

Comment: You can use "Inspect element" function in Chrome browser to view full path of datatable.

Comment: RongNK where can I fidn the full path?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the fullpath - `nzTableForm:nzTable`

Comment: RongNK take a look at the picture I added

Comment: I use Primefaces from 3.2 to 3.5, i don't have your issue.http://i283.photobucket.com/albums/kk308/breakbk/Untitled.jpg

Comment: If not, you can use firebug(firefox extendsion) to check request and respone between client and server, i think you use dialog to add new record and update to datatable, you need check again your java code.

Comment: Yes, this is true,however, I use the dialog to delete records and afterwards update the table, this is working tho.

Comment: I just want to be able to refresh the datatable even if nothing happend, I need that because I have a multiple select dataTable and there are some issues if I dont reload the dataTable afte I close the dialog and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can managed ajax event for each component inside dialog for example:

```
   <p:dialog id="zuordnenDialog" widgetVar="zuordnenDialogW" closeOnEscape="true" dynamic="true"
        header="Zuordnung" appendToBody="false" draggable="true" modal="true" resizable="false">

      <p:selectOneMenu id="idp" value="#{...}" converter="clientesConverter"  panelStyle="width:500px"  
                                         effect="fade" var="p" style="width:500px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">  

                            <f:selectItems value="#{comunMB.itemsClientes}"/>  

                            <f:ajax execute="@this"  listener="#{...}" render="table1 table2 table..." />
                        </p:selectOneMenu> 

    </p:dialog>
```

In this way change is showing in the table (or other component) while dialog is edited. Also you can use inplace component.