# Reload <p:tab> info with <p:commandButton> action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:tabView>` with 2 tabs. The first one contains student details and the second one contains a table of all students.

```
<p:tab title="List">
    <p:dataTable id="studentsTable" value="#{studentMB.allStudents}" var="student">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="ID"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{student.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Name"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{student.name}"/>
        </p:colum>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="Details" onclick="tabVar.select(0);" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:tab>
```

When the "Details" button in the table is pressed, then I would like to show the selected student in the first tab. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces tabview has activeIndex attribute, you can bind to bean variable:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{studentMB.tabindex}">
```

In each commandButton action, you pass value to determine student.

```
<p:commandButton update=":tabView" value="Details" actionListener="#{studentMB.handUpdate(student)}" />
```

Bean:

```
public void handUpdate(StudentType stValue){
        // get student detail
    }
```

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: I try and I get the error `Cannot find component with identifier ":tabView" referenced from "j_idt18:tabView:studentsTable:0:j_idt117`

Comment: you must set "<full path>:tabView"

Comment: You can get <full path> from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807837/update-form-from-dialog/15807979#15807979

Comment: I found ""j_idt18:tabView", you must set ID for parent of tabView, then you take: update=":parent_id:tabView"